# How to programmatically configure a proxy server for connectivity on the local network to the internet using a windows application

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How to programmatically configure a proxy server for connectivity on the local network to the internet using a windows application.

Please suggest a good example/reference.

Screenshot shows the  windows application form for setting proxy server 
[image: Proxy Setting]

Comment: Not clear. Is it that through your application you want to set proxy settings for your system? The screen shot you have shown is of FireFox. Firefox has its own settings. It does not picks proxy settings as set on windows OS

Comment: Sorry,I will update new screen shot

Comment: btw, if you press Alt+PrintScreen you will print screen only current windows, not all desktop so you need to crop the resulting image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Setting Windows internet connection proxy from C#](http://huddledmasses.org/setting-windows-internet-connection-proxy-from-c/). Use this link as reference

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you are using to do the internet traffic. If you are using a `WebRequest`, or anything that implements it, you can use the `WebProxy` object. This provides many properties for implementing this.

E.g.:

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("192.168.1.1:12345", true);
```

The above creates the proxy according to your settings, and bypasses on local. Now you can set this to your web request, or web service calls under the `Object.Proxy` property.

Links:

- MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy(v=VS.90).aspx
- Example Web Proxy Use - http://snipplr.com/view/16450/example-web-proxy-use/